# Creating a Post with a larger photo size

Tags: facebook, photo

When using the Facebook Graph API and including a Picture with a post, the picture always appears as a small thumbnail.  Is there a way to make the picture larger like it appears when you upload a photo and share it?

Answer (score 1):

No, the size of that photo is controlled by facebook and the only thing you can do is playing around with the relative size of the photo you use so that it would look slightly bigger (you should use pictures with landscape layout as opposed to portrait to get a 'slightly' bigger photo.

The hack you can use to do that is what apps like Instagram and Path did: Each time someone uploads a photo, they upload the photo to an album named "Instagram/Path photos" and include the link to the original photo in the caption (in your case,the link to the original article).

However, in order to do that, you users must grant you additional permissions on Facebook and they may not like the idea of uploading photos to another album, so I (personally) wouldn't go that way.